# WIF Extension for SAML 2.0 Protocol + WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, wif, saml

I'm looking for how to configure SP, and how to implement WCF service and client they talks saml2 protocol, NOT WS-Trust. with WIF Extension for SAML 2.0 Protocol.

I'm using ADFS 2.0 as an IdP.

I can find details of how to configure IdP and SP that provide "aspx" to web browser, but I cannot find about "svc" (provides WCF service to WCF client application).

How can I configure/implement SP,WCF Service and Client talks saml2 protocol using "WIF Extension" ?